# Php OpenID fault in google accounts

Tags: php, openid, google-openid

I'm use"PHP OpenID" for login with Google accounts into my site(forum and wiki) but when i send my profile address and i signed in bellow error are shown:

OpenID authentication failed: Nonce already used or out of range

1.where is the problem and how can i fix it?

2.how can get picture and another information's from a Google profile?
3.how can i get the following list and other information about followers and ... from it?

my test page is:
http://www.osdev.ir/openid/

Comment: Did you tried this: http://remysharp.com/2007/12/21/how-to-integrate-openid-as-your-login-system/comment-page-1/#comment-241906

Answer (score 1):

The 'nonce already used or out of range' means that the nonce returned by the OpenID provider has expired -- this is checked against to prevent replay attacks.

This *could* be because your system time is out of whack (at least, that's when I got the error).

Comment: How do you correct the system time, if that is the case?